# Django running on Apache+WSGI and apache SSL proxying

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy, django

I'm trying to rewrite all requests for my Django server running on apache+WSGI ( inside my local network) and configured as the WSGI's wiki how to, except that I set a virtualhost for it.

The server which from I want to rewrite requests is another apache server listening on port 
80. I can manage it to work well if I don't try to enable SSL connection as the required way to connect. 
But I need all requests to Django server encrypted with SSL so I generally used this directive to achieve this ( on my public webserver ):

```
    Alias /dirname "/var/www/dirname"
    

        SSLVerifyClient      none
        SSLOptions           +FakeBasicAuth
        SSLRequireSSL
        AuthName             "stuff name"
        AuthType             Basic
        AuthUserFile         /etc/httpd/djangoserver.passwd
        require              valid-user

        # redirect all request to django.test:80 
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule   (.*)$  http://django.test/$1 [P]
```

This configuration works if I try to load a specific page trough the external server from my browser. It is not working clicking my django application urls ( even tough the url seems correct when I put my mouse over).

The url my public server is trying to serve use  http ( instead of https ) and the directory "dirname" I specified on my apache configuration disappear, so it says that the page was not found. I think it depends on Django and its WSGI handler . Does anybody went trough my same problem?

PS: I have already tried to modify the WSGI script . I'm Using Django 1.0.3, Apache 2.2 on a Fedora10 (inside), Apache 2.2 on the public server.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Fab

Comment: See followups where you posted on Django user list.

Answer (score 1):

My solution thanks to Graham:

```
<Location /dirname>
    SSLVerifyClient      none
    SSLOptions           +FakeBasicAuth
    SSLRequireSSL
    AuthName             "name Authentication"
    AuthType             Basic
    AuthUserFile         /etc/httpd/stuff.passwd
    require              valid-user

    RequestHeader set X-Url-Scheme https


</Location>

ProxyPass /dirname http://django.test/dirname
ProxyPassReverse /dirname http://django.test/dirname
```

On django.test I added this :

```
 SetEnvIf X-Url-Scheme https HTTPS=1
```

after

```
  WSGIScriptAlias /dirname /path_to_wsgi_script/django.wsgi
```